# Google directions for autocompleted search Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-directions-api

I am using google maps which shows current location as well as the user being able to search and select from autocompleted suggestions places on this map. The next thing I would like is to allow the user to get directions from their current location to the marker they choose and tap on. Any suggestions about how I implement this? I have uploaded the GoogleDirectionsAPI but am confused what next... I have seen code which accommodates a specific place or coordinate whereas I will want there to not be a set destination but whatever the destination is created by the autocomplete.

Thanks

my code for the autocomplete google maps search:

```
   func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15.0)
        self.vwGMap.camera = camera
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)
        marker.title = place.name
        marker.snippet = place.formattedAddress
        marker.map = self.vwGMap
        marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor.blue)
        marker.tracksViewChanges = true
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Place name: ", place.name)
        print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
        print("Place placeID: ", place.placeID)
        print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)
        print("Place Coordinate:", place.coordinate)
        //The printing only happens in the terminal
        let newPlace = StoredPlace(name: place.name, address: place.formattedAddress!, placeID: place.placeID)
        storedPlaces.append(newPlace)

}



    func viewController(_ viewcontroller: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print("ERROR AUTO COMPLETE \(error)")
    }

    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

@IBAction func searchWithAddress(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchWithAddress = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    searchWithAddress.delegate = self
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment
    filter.country = "UK"
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.present(searchWithAddress, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to implement the google api for searching the location.

```
func hitForPlace(searchText:String)
{
        arrPlaceList.removeAll()
        viewLine.hidden = false

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=\(searchText)&sensor=true&key=\(googleMapApiKey)")!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do {
                if data != nil{
                    let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as!  NSDictionary
                    print_debug(dic)

                    for var count = 0;count<dic["predictions"]?.count;count = count+1
                    {
                        self.arrPlaceList.append(dic["predictions"]![count]["description"] as! String)
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.placeTableShow(true)
                        self.tablePlace.reloadData()
                    });

                }
            }catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have the search for location through using the Autocomplete widget in google places. but now i need to implement directions which as far as i understand is done with googlemapsdirectionsAPI, is that correct? Ill amend my post above to show my code for the autocomplete section. where do i go from here to get directions from current location to autocompleted place?